# A good method for user creation in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

I customize model as below.

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth.models import (
    BaseUserManager, AbstractBaseUser, _user_has_perm
)
from django.core import validators
from django.utils.translation import ugettext_lazy as _
from django.utils import timezone


class AccountManager(BaseUserManager):
    def create_user(self, request_data, **kwargs):
        now = timezone.now()
        if not request_data['email']:
            raise ValueError('Users must have an email address.')

        if request_data['profile']:
            profile = request_data['profile']
        else:
            profile = None

        user = self.model(
            username=request_data['username'],
            email=self.normalize_email(request_data['email']),
            is_active=True,
            last_login=now,
            date_joined=now,
            profile=profile
        )

        user.set_password(request_data['password'])
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user

    def create_superuser(self, username, email, password, **extra_fields):
        request_data = {
            'username': username,
            'email': email,
            'password': password
        }
        user = self.create_user(request_data)
        user.is_active = True
        user.is_staff = True
        user.is_admin = True
        # user.is_superuser = True
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user


class Account(AbstractBaseUser):
    username    = models.CharField(_('username'), max_length=30, unique=True)
    first_name  = models.CharField(_('first name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    last_name   = models.CharField(_('last name'), max_length=30, blank=True)
    email       = models.EmailField(verbose_name='email address', max_length=255, unique=True)
    profile     = models.CharField(_('profile'), max_length=255, blank=True)
    is_active   = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    is_staff    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_admin    = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    date_joined = models.DateTimeField(_('date joined'), default=timezone.now)
    delete      = models.BooleanField(default=0)

    objects = AccountManager()

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'email'
    REQUIRED_FIELDS = ['username']

    def user_has_perm(user, perm, obj):
        return _user_has_perm(user, perm, obj)

    def has_perm(self, perm, obj=None):
        return _user_has_perm(self, perm, obj=obj)

    def has_module_perms(self, app_label):
        return self.is_admin

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    @property
    def is_superuser(self):
        return self.is_admin

    class Meta:
        db_table = 'api_user'
        swappable = 'AUTH_USER_MODEL'
```

The difference from the default User Model is the use of email for login and addition of the `profile` field.
In the meantime, `python manage.py createsuperuser` can be executed without problems.


Also, `views.py` is implemented as follows.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from rest_framework import authentication, permissions, generics
from rest_framework_jwt.settings import api_settings
from rest_framework.generics import GenericAPIView
from rest_framework.exceptions import AuthenticationFailed
from rest_framework.response import Response
from django.db import transaction

from rest_framework import status, viewsets, filters
from rest_framework.views import APIView

from .serializer import AccountSerializer
from .models import Account, AccountManager


class UserListView(APIView):
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        queryset = Account.objects.all()
        serializer = AccountSerializer(queryset, many=True, data=request.data)

        if serializer.is_valid():
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)


class AuthRegister(generics.CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny,)
    queryset = Account.objects.all()
    serializer_class = AccountSerializer

    @transaction.atomic
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = AccountSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

`Serializer.py` is implemented as follows

```
from django.contrib.auth import update_session_auth_hash
from rest_framework import serializers

from .models import Account, AccountManager


class AccountSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Account
        fields = ('id', 'username', 'email', 'profile', 'password')

    def create(self, validated_data):
        return AccountManager.create_user(**validated_data)
```

If there is a POST request in AuthRegister, we want to implement user creation via `AccountManager.create_user` via AccountSerializer.
However, when POST is executed with the above code, `TypeError: create_user () missing 2 required positional arguments: 'self' and 'request_data' error occurs.

How can I improve my code?

Also, in Django Rest Framework, please let me know if you have a better user-created API implementation method.


Regards.

Comment: try：`return AccountManager.create_user(request_data=validated_data)`

Comment: @Ykh  I get an error `TypeError: create_user() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'` ...
thanks.

Comment: ok,forget about use `AccountManager`,just `User.objects.create_user(request_data=validated_data)` will fine

Comment: @Ykh Great!`return Account.objects.create_user (request_data = validated_data)` worked fine.but,I do not understand why it works properly, so I will study.

Comment: I don't know either.I will figure out in my spare time,i will tell you then.